# Weird background icons behind "Not the answer you're looking for?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a weird arrow behind the "Not the answer you're looking for".

After a few search, it might be related to [this question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/449/the-expand-this-arrow-in-the-updated-reputation-view-is-missing).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.